# Mac Terminal How to delete an FTP folder

Tags: macos, terminal, ftp

I am trying to delete a VERY large folder that has subfolders, each containing hundreds of png files ranging from 2 KB to 20 KB. In terminal I do `ftp`, then `ftp (hostname) (port)` Then I enter the user and then the password. That works successfully and I have full access. I want to delete `plugins/dynmap` So I do `rm plugins/dynmap`
Then it says
`450 Can't remove directory /plugins/dynmap`

Answer (score 1):

Use `rmdir` instead of `rm`. The latter is meant for individual files, while `rmdir` is what deletes a directory.

Depending on your version and implementation of the FTP command, it could be that `rmdir` first empties the directory for you. If not, you may have to delete its contents before deleting the directory.

Comment: I did `rmdir plugins/dynmap` and it said `450 Can't remove directory /plugins/dynmap.
`
Maybe the file is to big?

Comment: What else should I do? @Jarmund

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up letting FileZilla do the work, slowly, but it still worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a directory using rm it must be empty. You can alternatively delete all of the contents and the directory with "rm -r " followed be the directory name.